# How to apply custom carts rules to quote in magento?

Tags: quote, rules

we are creating a module in which we are creating custom rules to apply on cart. Rules creation working fine. But, don't know how to apply that rules to cart/quote.

Please share your views, I m stuck in this from last 3days.

Comment: Please try follow bellow like step http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html

Comment: Thx for reply but Its a generate-rule process, But I need how to apply rule on quote that doesn't have coupon code. Means I have custom discount 20% rule on above totel $100. And its shopping cart rule but its created through our extension and also saved in our extension table's .

Comment: have you not created in shopping cart rules?

Comment: Yes , we have created